# Hibernate NULL values of map not added (xml mapping)

Tags: java, hibernate

I mapped following map collection:

```
<map name="customFields" table="table_name" fetch="select">
    <key column="primary_id" />
    <map-key-many-to-many column="custom_id" class="CustomField" />
    <many-to-many column="other_id" class="AnotherClass" />
</map>
```

This works great; all records are added to the map if columns '`primary_id`', '`custom_id`' and '`other_id`' are all filled with a value.

But when 'other_id' column is empty, that record is not added to the map. Is there a property or something I can force Hibernate to add these records to the Java Map as well?

*Visualisation*

```
+------------+-----------+----------+
| primary_id | custom_id | other_id | Added? 
+------------+-----------+----------+
|          1 |        53 | 124      | YES   
|          2 |        98 | 288      | YES   
|          3 |        18 | NULL     | NO    
+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long searching documentations and such, I just found out that Hibernate does not support NULL values in a map:

- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-358
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-772

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the not-null="false" in your mapping

`<many-to-many column="other_id" not-null="false" class="AnotherClass" />`

Comment: I don't think a `not-null` attribute is allowed. If I add one, i stumble upon a `Attribute "not-null" must be declared for element type "many-to-many"` error!